# Is a queue of lambdas a good design pattern for a work queue in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have to make a thread-safe work queue which can have work popped on in different threads and it will process it on a worker thread. The work can be very generic so I was thinking using lambdas with capture as a good way to allow this. I have the following code as a starter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional> 
typedef std::function<void()> Task;
typedef std::vector<Task> TaskQueue;

class Queue 
{
   public:
    void flush() {
        for (auto it : m_queue) {
            it();
        }
    }
   // will add thread safe locks later.        
    void queue(Task task) {
        m_queue.push_back(task);
    }

private:
    TaskQueue m_queue;
};
Queue q;

class WorkMaker
{
public: 

    WorkMaker(int inA) : m_a(inA) {}

    void MakeWork() {
        q.queue([&]{
            std::cout << this->m_a << std::endl;
        });
    }


private:
    int m_a;
};

int main()
{
  WorkMaker w1(1);
  WorkMaker w2(2);
  w1.MakeWork();
  w2.MakeWork();
  q.flush();
  return 0;
}
```

Is there something inherently unperformant about this code or will the compiler optimize it out? Also is passing a lambda into a `std::function` argument by value copying the lambda or just the pointer to it?

EDIT:

I think i can solve the problem of memory ownership by using shared_ptr's and passing them into the lambda instead. Consider the following modification:

```
typedef std::function<void()> Task;
typedef std::deque<Task> TaskQueue;

class Queue 
{
   public:
    void flush() {
        while (!m_queue.empty()) {
            auto it = m_queue.front();
            m_queue.pop_front();
            it();
        }
    }
   // will add thread safe locks later.        
    void queue(Task task) {
        m_queue.push_back(task);
    }

private:
    TaskQueue m_queue;
};
Queue q;


class WorkMaker : public std::enable_shared_from_this<WorkMaker>
{
public: 

    WorkMaker(int inA) : m_a(inA) {}
    ~WorkMaker() { std::cout << "Destroy " << m_a << std::endl;  }
    void MakeWork() {
        std::shared_ptr<WorkMaker> self = shared_from_this();
        q.queue([self]{
             std::cout << self->m_a << std::endl;
        });
    }
    int m_a;
};

int main()
{
  {
    auto w1 = std::make_shared<WorkMaker>(1);   
    auto w2 = std::make_shared<WorkMaker>(2);    
    w1->MakeWork();
    w2->MakeWork();
  }
  q.flush();
  return 0;
}
```

I get the desired output as :

```
1
Destroy 1
2
Destory 2
```

Comment: When `WorkMaker` gets deallocated it leaves an invalid reference inside the lambda which may crash. And since you don't know when the work will be done you never know when you can deallocate the `WorkMaker`.

Comment: If there was no capture or the capture was by value of literals would the lambda still be around if `WorkMaker` is destroyed?

Comment: The `TaskQueue` owns a `std::function` object that manages its own copy of the lambda object. This copy of the lambda will be around as long as its owning `std::function`, and therefore potentially survive `WorkMaker`. Hence, `WorkMaker` should, in one way or the other, dequeue all its pending tasks that maintain a reference when it is deleted.

Comment: @ThomasBPreusser The last bit sounds a bit messy... Do you think then overall this is a bad design?

Comment: @IvajloDonev This is very common design, you aren't the inventor of a thread safe queue. In fact writing one using the latest C++11 is one of the questions I use to interview people. I would recommend templating yours in the fashion of the standard, and not coupling it so deeply with what sort of data it contains. Hint: you'll likely want a condition_variable, a mutex, and to use a deque

Comment: Why is `WorkMaker` a class and not a function? You have to be careful that the lambda actually captures the variables by value and not the this- or stackpointer, but I forgot the rules for that.

Comment: `WorkMaker` is a class because it owns the data that it wants the worker to execute. It can also generate multiple jobs with the same data (depending on the type of job). I just wanted to illustrate that instead of passing all the data needed for a job to be done on a queue to the queue itself that data would remain in the `WorkMakers`. But the more I think about it the more I think this is not a good idea concerning data ownership and object lifetime.

Comment: why not use boost::asio::io_service? it is designed for purpose you are trying achieve

Answer (score 1):

The `std::function` will make a private copy of the function pointer, lambda or whatever it refers to. Typically, this copy is referenced from the `std::function` object so that further copying is later avoided.

There is nothing particularly slow with using `std::function` objects this way. However, you should probably think about replacing the `std::vector` by a `std::deque`.

Comment: With no pop front, no reason to use deque.

Comment: Actually, copyinf a `std::function` will copy the underlying functor.